# Platform Access Disabled: Access temporarily disabled due to changes to the Facebook Platform

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I work with a web app that asks users for permissions to post on their behalf. For this, we call the FB login window (https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth) to ask for the permissions. The permissions we request in the scope are:

```
scope: 'public_profile, user_friends, read_insights, manage_pages, publish_actions, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_messaging, publish_pages, ads_read, ads_management'
```

everything has been working fine until today when we started getting this error:

> Platform Access Disabled: Access temporarily disabled due to changes to the Facebook Platform

We have enabled https and we are using non-deprecated versions of the API and dialogue.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's pages_messaging permission, Facebook not allow it at this time. Please remove it for now until Facebook update.

Comment: Do you have a link to a statement they made?
I have this issue too, but I'm not sure where to track it because I don't see it on their issues page.
Or does this fall under the general "API Data Access Update" issue?

Comment: Yes, this did the trick! hopefully FB gets their sh%%t together soon!

Thanks

Comment: this worked for me, too.
not sure where to track the issue though. Its even happening in my test app with a test user...

Comment: if we removed 'pages_messaging', we cannot grant the 'pages_messaging' rights from new register users, isn't it?

Comment: This is the official statement: https://messenger.fb.com/newsroom/messenger-platform-changes-in-development/

Comment: How can I remove the `pages_messaging`?

Comment: This problem did seem to get fixed for a week or so but we are experiencing this same messaging again today.

Comment: in my experience `read_page_mailboxes` should be removed... but still don't know why

Answer (score 2):

You need a Login Review in your app for use 'user_friends' permission

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/03/26/facebook-platform-changes/

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, but I'm not requesting user_friends; I'm only requesting: "manage_pages,pages_messaging,public_profile,email".

It worked recently, plus its only a test app with a test user... I'm not sure why a test app would be affected, especially if it was working before and we're not using this particular perm they're changing.

Answer (score 0):

Please wait for Facebook developer team update on the below issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/104197713763517/
https://messenger.fb.com/newsroom/messenger-platform-changes-in-development/